# Javascript: function and its argument

Tags: javascript, arguments

I've a problem with my function and its `arguments`... this is the code:

```
function elab(){

   var up = arguments[0];
   var id = arguments[1];
   len = arguments.length - 3;

   for(var a = 1; a <= 10; a++){

      arg = (arguments[2] + a); // id tag html : [nome][num]
      document.getElementById(arg).style.display = "block";
   }

   for (var i = 3; i < len; i++) {

      alert('test1');
      document.getElementById(arguments[i]).style.display = "none";
      alert('test2');
   }

   change_price(up, id);
}
```

The script hangs at the second cycle: it prints `'test1'` but not `'test2'`.
Where is the error?
thx all ;)

Comment: What is `id tag html : [nome][num]` supposed to do?

Comment: did you mean `(arguments[(2+a)])` ?

Comment: It probably doesn't hang, it's more likely to have tripped on an error; the most likely error would be that the element couldn't be found.

Comment: What does the console says?
document.getElementById(arguments[i]) probably returns undefined, so You can't access it's properties.

Comment: `document.getElementById` surely can not find the `element` by value of `arguments[i]`, check the value of `arguments[i]`

Comment: @user2357112 It's a comment to indicate that `arguments[2]` is the prefix of the actual DOM element and `a` is the index ... so `foo1`, `foo2`, etc.

Comment: @Jack: Aren't comments supposed to start with `//`?

Comment: @user2357112 Yes, they ought to.

Answer (score 0):

Note that this advice should be used for all things unsure:

```
for (var i = 3; i < len; i++) {
    var node = document.getElementById(arguments[i]);

    if (node) {
        node.style.display = "none"; // block
    }
}
```

In other words, always test if an element can be found if you're not 100% sure. To be even more pedantic:

```
for (var i = 3; i < len; i++) {
    var node = document.getElementById(arguments[i]);

    if (!node) {
        throw "Element " + arguments[i] + " not found.";
    }
    node.style.display = "none"; // block
}
```